Old Website SQL DB & files - is there a way to import to a new site?
I built a financial website / marketplace by using wordpress approximately 9 years ago. We had a custom domain for the site and hosted the wordpress on that domain. Our host literally folded at the time and because I wasn't monitoring communications with them, we eventually lost everything.
I let the domain expire with time & the business idea BUT, after many communications with the host at the time (who folded) pleading for them to at the very least send me relevant files / database, they did BUT I never did anything with it as I ended up focused on other businesses. I am not a developer - rather a guy who can design websites and savvy enough to do it all myself without code at a good level via wordpress etc... - but not savvy on the dev, import, SQL stuff or migrating/renewing old content/domain to new site.
I have an SQL file provided from them (database I guess) & the basic site files that appear to be just the wordpress theme I guess as I can't really see custom content within them that is mine. I was wondering if there is a way to import/migrate this to a new wordpress site/domain or simply to view it right now? I am happy to get someone to help me if the content is valid. Would I need to get a wordpress / SQL person to do it? OR, is this content basically lost?
I'm looking to renew the business idea so a lot of content would be new but we did create a few hundred pages of content which as you know, will take a year or two sadly... We did a lot of work on this but let it fold due to other priorities.
Would love to renew this content as a starting place.
Any advice helpful. Thanks
Mike

As with any CMS that uses a database, WordPress stores content in the database so you wouldn't see it in the files.
It should be possible to recreate the site from what you have. If you'd like to work on it on your local machine then upload to a hosting account when you're ready, LocalWP is a good tool to get the prerequisites installed and running.
You'll need to import your SQL file into the database (making sure that wp-config.php is pointing to the table generated), and place your theme files in /wp-content/themes/themename
